# How to add footer in navigation drawer?

Tags: html, css, material-design-lite

I am trying to make it so that in the drawer menu I have an option like settings sitting at the bottom of the screen and when you scroll up or down that it will stay at the bottom of the drawer visible part of the drawer an example to visualize it is the android inbox app, if you look at the menu you will see that the settings and help&feedback buttons are visible at the bottom independent of the scrolling position (can't post picture because reputation is <10).

Some information about how I'm trying to do this, I started making my mobile focused site with the  MDL android template https://getmdl.io/templates/android-dot-com/index.html and i havent changed anything to the drawer menu except added more items to it. And the amount of items in my drawer menu is starting to get pretty long and to make it a bit easier so user don't have to scroll down the entire menu I want to have it stay at the bottom of the screen in the drawer menu.

Thank you in advance and sorry for my English. I got pretty far with my site thanks to StackOverflow but I couldn't find a lot on how to do this.

Comment: Add a `jsfiddle` example of what you currently have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [this pen](https://codepen.io/ksiabani/pen/LjqLEa).

Basically, you can make reuse of MDL components to achieve this:

1. Use `mdl-layout__header` inside `mdl-layout__drawer`. That will place a toolbar after navigation items
2. Use `mdl-layout-spacer` after `nav` and before `mdl-layout-header` to *push* the toolbar to the bottom of the drawer

Comment: It works until the nav becomes so full that the area becomes scrollable and then the footer just goes to the bottom of the drawer and doesn't behave as a footer anymore.

Comment: Also, I don't think it works on mobile, it doesn't show it at all. ithis also happens on desktop when i make the window less wide, the thing is that i dont have an @media tag at all.

Comment: happens at 1024px with think it is somewhere in the mdl css.

Comment: This was not meant to be a complete solution, but rather to show you how you can use mdl components. Surely you will need some CSS here and there to suit it to your needs. I have updated my pen. Hope it helps.